# Adding text to image with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, image, text, overlay

I'm trying to add text to image with jquery and PHP. Here is what I've got:

jQuery:

```
function generateImage() {
    var dataString = '&text=' + killCounter;
    //alert (dataString);return false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bin/image-generator.php",
        data:  dataString, 
        success: function() {

        }
    });
    return false;
}generateImage();
```

And I'm obviously sending this to image-generator.php which looks like this:

PHP:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('template.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
$font_path = 'font.ttf';
$text = $_POST['text'];
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $font_path, $text);
imagejpeg($jpg_image, "/images");
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

Unfortunatly nothing happens. I can't find anywhere new image with text. It is also not displaying in browser. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `killCounter` when the AJAX runs?

Comment: "it is also not displaying in browser"...well you never asked it to do that, so that's not surprising.

Comment: have you actually checked for any PHP errors? Make sure PHP is set up to log errors and warnings to a file, so you can look for problems after the script ran. See https://stackify.com/php-error-logs-guide/ for guidance.

Comment: @ADyson it's generated before killCounter = 0; and how can i ask for saving the image? I not wanna display it in browser but save it in /images - i thought this is it: imagejpeg($jpg_image, "/images");

Comment: yes that _should_ do it in theory. Although you need to specify a filename, not just a folder name, and you may need to supply an absolute path on disk, not a relative one. And there could be issues such as filesystem permissions, or problems occurring in the code before that, even. That's why I said to check for errors - see my previous comment.

Comment: And if you don't want to display it in the browser, you don't need `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`. You'd be better returning some kind of message or status code in the response, to indicate whether the operation succeeded or not.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson changing path to absolute path on disk fixed that - but it cames out another problem - it doesn't add text. I need to run some more tests.

Comment: @ADyson i finally make it working - but i cannot make the font big enough is there some kind of possibility to do that with php ?

Comment: How big did you want it? What's the biggest size which worked? It may depend on what size is supported by the font you've chosen.

Comment: @ADyson I need it really big - it has to be on 1800x1800 image so like 200px in size. I'm using Montserrat black font but it does not work with 'imagettftext' yet it is working with 'imagestring' - but that does not support font size over 5 points.